# React fetch request returning an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, fetch

I have a 3D globe that when you click on a country, returns an overlay of users.

I've previously had everything working just a file of randomised, mock user data in a local file. However I've now received the actual database (a AWS one) and I can't seem to get the fetch to return what I need. It should accept a signal from country click then return a list of users from this and show them in the pop up.

I've taken out the actual database for now (confidential) but this is working correctly on postman and a simplified fetch request I created. It doesn't seem to work within the wider context of this app.

At this stage, it doesn't break but it just returns an empty array in the console.

console.log output for this.state...
`this is the state {overlay: true, users: Array(0), country: "Nigeria"}`

````
import { onCountryClick } from "../Scene3D/AppSignals";
import OutsideClickHandler from "react-outside-click-handler";
import Users from "../Users";

import "./style.scss";

class Overlay extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { overlay: false, users: [], country: [] };
    this.openOverlay = this.openOverlay.bind(this);
    this.closeOverlay = this.closeOverlay.bind(this);
    this.fetchUsers = this.fetchUsers.bind(this);
  }

  openOverlay() {
    this.setState({ overlay: true });
  }

  closeOverlay() {
    this.setState({ overlay: false });
  }

  fetchUsers() {
    fetch(
      "**AWS***"
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ users: data.users }));
  }

  onCountryClick = (country, users) => {
    this.openOverlay();
    this.fetchUsers();
    this.setState({ country });
    console.log("users", this.state.users);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.onCountrySignal = onCountryClick.add(this.onCountryClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.onCountrySignal.detach();
  }

  render() {
    const country = this.state.country;
    const users = this.state.users;

    return (
      <OutsideClickHandler
        onOutsideClick={() => {
          this.closeOverlay();
        }}
      >
        <div className="users-container">
          {this.state.overlay && (
            <>
              <h1>{country}</h1>
              {users}
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </OutsideClickHandler>
    );
  }
}

export default Overlay;```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWOlx.png
````

Comment: Have you tried fetching the same with postman?

Comment: @Zydnar yep - all returns as expected with postman

Comment: @LauraAnnabel89, I suspect this line ```this.fetchUsers();
    this.setState({ users, country });``` in ```fetchUsers()``` also you are setting the state and again you are setting the state after fetch users with the parameters of the function.. Can you eloborate on this case??

Comment: fetch is async so is setState, maybe try this.setState({ users: data.users }, callback) or do what you want in componentDidUpdate. Also fetchUsers does not return the promise from fetch so the order of execution is unpredictible.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan apologies that was just a wip version, I didn't intend to update state twice, have updated the code

Comment: @LauraAnnabel89, Can you use ```console.log(this.state)``` alone and update the result please??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan yep done thanks

Comment: I'm wondering if you are getting a CORS error - is there anything in the console to suggest this?  or in the devtools Network tab for this request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
 onCountryClick = (country, users) => {
  this.openOverlay();
  this.fetchUsers();
  this.setState({ country });
  console.log("users", this.state.users);
 };
```

fetchUsers function is asynchronous and taken out from the original flow of execution, And the original execution stack continue to execute the `console.log("users", this.state.users)` which is empty at this time because fetchUsers function is not yet done executing. to prove it try to console log inside fetchUsers and you'll see who executed first.

Comment: Thanks @meron-veloso, that makes sense however I'm still getting an empty console log from inside fetch users so I get the same result from console logging in fetch users too

Comment: go logs inside the `.then()` function. the data you're looking for is there. that function get executed if the asynchronous function is done.  this might help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function